# Could these passages be viewed as corollary referring to “Logos”?

Tags: john, revelation, hebrews

John 1:1-3

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. He was in the beginning with God. All things were made through Him, and without Him nothing was made that was made.

Hebrews 1:2

> …, through whom also He made the worlds;…

Hebrews 11:3

> By faith we understand that **the worlds were framed by the word of God**, so that the things which are seen were not made of things which are visible.

Revelation 3:14

> …, the Beginning of the creation of God:

Comment: Do you mean corollary in the sense of teaching about the Logos or Jesus?

Comment: I am not clear as to what 'corollary' means in this context. I think that more clarity and detail and a fuller explanation is rrequired in this question.

Answer (score 3):

Of the OP's texts, only John 1:1-3 mentions the Logos.  Indeed,

- Heb 11:3 does not mention the Logos, but uses the word, "rhema" = spoken word
- Heb 1:2 does not mention the Logos, but Heb 1:3 mentions "rhema" = spoken word
- Rev 3:14 does not mention the Logos

**Conclusion #1**

Only John 1:1-3 teach anything about the Logos (of the OP's texts).

Despite the above conclusion. all, four of the OP's texts teach about some aspect of Christology, or the nature of Jesus Christ.  More specifically, all teach that Jesus is the creator of all things because the "Logos" is clearly identified as Jesus in two passages:

- John 1:14 - **The Word (Logos)** became flesh and made His dwelling among us. We have seen His glory, the glory of the one and only [Son] from the Father, full of grace and truth.
- Rev 19:13 - He is dressed in a robe dipped in blood, and His name is **The Word (Logos)** of God.

Indeed, BDAG gives this as one of the meanings of the Greek, "logos" #3 as:

> the independent personified expression of God, the Logos

With this in mind, the other texts of the OP all declare some aspect of Christology, specifically:

- John 1:1-3 declares the pre-existence of Christ and His eternity with the Father and His creatorship of all things
- Heb 1:2 declares Christ's creatorship
- Heb 11:3 is more controversial as this only discusses the creation of the universe by the word (rhema) of God and thus clearly alludes to Gen 1 where we have the repeated expression, "And God said ...".  Thus, Heb 11:3 does not say anything specific about Christ (explicitly) but only about God.  However, by comparison with the other texts, this appears to imply that Jesus is God simply because the other texts so plainly say that Jesus is creator and that God is creator; and hence, Jesus is God.
- Rev 3:14 is also controversial, but only by people who misunderstand the Greek word "arche".  See appendix below.  This texts simply says that Jesus is the initiator and originator of all creation.

**Conclusion #2**

Two of the texts quoted by the OP, viz, Heb 1:2, Rev 3:14 both point to Jesus Christ as creator of the universe and all things (without using the personified expression, "Logos".)  The same thing is taught in John 1:10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:10.  However, Heb 11:3 does not specifically discuss Jesus, but by comparison with these others (see also Isa 44:24, 45:18), implies that Jesus is God.

**APPENDIX - Note about ἀρχὴ**

One of the important/pivotal words in Rev 3:14 is ἀρχὴ (arche) which has two distinct sets of meanings:

- when it refers to either an inanimate object or an abstract idea, it always means "beginning or start", eg, John 2:11, Heb 7:3, Matt 24:8, Mark 13:8, etc.
- however, when it refers to a person, the word means "originator", "one with whom a process begins" (BDAG), eg, Col 1:18, Rev 1:8, 3:14, 21:6, 22;13, OR, the authority figure who initiates activity or a process, eg, Luke 20:20, 12:11, Titus 3:1, etc.

Thus, Rev 3:14 cannot mean that Jesus is the beginning of God's creation; but must refer to Jesus being the initiator or originator of God's creation.

Comment: Up-voted +1 especially regarding _arche_ and its twin meanings and the two words _rhema_ and _logos_.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "yes" except for the Hebrews 11:3 verse. The Greek word for word is "rema" and properly means spoken words. Consider in the Old Testament Psalms 33:6, "By the word of the Lord were the heavens made; and all the host of them by the breath of his mouth."

The other verses do "correlate" with the "Logos/Jesus Christ. There is one other thing to keep in mind with the Revelation 3:14 reference. Many groups who deny the deity of Jesus Christ use this verse as a proof text to show that Jesus was a created being.

That is not what the verse is teaching. If you look up the Greek word for "beginning" it is "arche." We get our English word "architect" from that word. An Architect creates/designs or is the origin of something to be made.

The following is from Strong's Lexicon.   https://biblehub.com/greek/746.htm You will also notice how the other verses you referenced back up this definition. One could also include Colossians 1:16.